# How to play keyboard click sound in custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, custom-keyboard

I had created custom keyboard with `UIView`.
However, I didn't hear the click sound of the keyboard.
So I tried following code, but I can't hear anything.
How can I play that keyboard click sound?

```
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                               pathForResource:@"Tock"
                                               ofType:@"aiff"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
    [click setVolume:0.15f];
    [click play];
```

And also I tried this:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0x450);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
```

Note that

> Use this method to play the standard system keyboard click in response
>   to a user tapping in a custom input or keyboard accessory view. A
>   click plays only if the user has enabled keyboard clicks in Settings >
>   Sounds, and only if the input view is itself enabled and visible.
>
> To enable a custom input or accessory view for input clicks, perform
>   the following two steps:
>
> Adopt the UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol in your input view class.
>   Implement the enableInputClicksWhenVisible delegate method to return
>   YES.

Comment: I followed the instructions, but however, there is no click sound on my keyboard. On system keyboard click sound works.

Answer (score 6):

Couldn't get any of this to work, but this worked for me:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104);
```

But still I had to subclass a `UIButton` and add the `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` Protocol to it.

Comment: This worked. I did not even have to add UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol. But it does not honor system setting of keyboard click sound. I'm on iOS 11.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift add an extension to the input view as follows;

```
extension UIInputView : UIInputViewAudioFeedback {

    public var enableInputClicksWhenVisible: Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

In the action method for your buttons call the following function:

```
    UIDevice.current.playInputClick()
```

Add the following property to your info.plist:

> NSExtension | NSExtensionAttributes | RequestsOpenAccess = YES

Comment: It plays sound even if we disable the keyboard sound from "phone settings" , any solution..

Comment: As i recollect, it works, but it's a caching issue. If you restart the device after making the settings change it will take effect.

Answer (score 2):

For swift there's actually an incredibly easy way to play keyboard sound effect.

first:

```
import AudioToolbox
```

then use this whenever you need the sound effect.

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0x450)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! What an amazing find!