# iOS 8 Custom Keyboard that play sounds

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, custom-keyboard

I'm trying to build a custom keyboard for iOS 8 that a custom play sound when a key is pressed. I'm using a `AVAudioPlayer` and small mp3-files.

This works fine in the simulator, but on a real device I don't get any sounds.

`RequestOpenAccess` is enabled.

Please not that I'm not trying to play the default keyboard click sound, but a custom sound. Most existing questions seems to be about the default system sound.

edit: I've also tried using .caf and .aiff files and loading and playing them with SystemSoundID.

Comment: Do you have any error or warnning in the console when you try to play the sound?

Comment: No, nothing. It's just silent. It's like the sound loads, but can't play because the app freeze for about the same time as the length of the audio.

Comment: If the app freeze maybe you can use Xcode Instruments like Time profiler to saw in which method the app freeze.

Comment: we need a little bit more information here - do you maybe have some code?

Comment: Here's a link to my small test project on BitBucket. It just tries to play the same sound for all the buttons. https://bitbucket.org/tfsjohan/phonetickeyboard/src

Answer (score 2):

This snippet plays custom sound in my keyboard project.

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your_custom_sound" 
                                                      ofType:@"mp3"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

Cited from:

[How to play tock sound when tapping custom keyboard buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496535/how-to-play-tock-sound-when-tapping-custom-keyboard-buttons)

Comment: There is no problem with performance.  By the way, the sound file size is 8KB in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm positive this is not your case but it often happens that the sound on the device is turned off. I made the mistake searching for an hour why sound didn't work. If it could only be that, it would be a quick fix ;)

Comment: Wish was that simple. :) I even made sure I have the default click sound on for the built in keyboard and can here that just fine.