# Play standard iOS keyboard click sound in Custom Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, audio, keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension

I was wondering if there's new API in iOS 8 that will allow you to play the standard keyboard click sound in a keyboard extension - and only play it if they have the keyboard clicks enabled and the device isn't on silent. I haven't seen such an API, and I haven't seen any questions about this.

I do know in previous iOS versions this was possible if you implemented a custom input or keyboard accessory view (via `[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];` after you adopt the `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` protocol and return `YES` in `enableInputClicksWhenVisible`). This was possible only in those situations. A keyboard extension is neither of those.

Is it possible to play the input click with a custom iOS keyboard?

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496535/how-to-play-tock-sound-when-tapping-custom-keyboard-buttons?rq=1) is related, but they wanted a custom sound, and the solution will not respect the user's preference for playing keyboard clicks - will always play them even when that option has been disabled.

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/a/10299080/2446155

Comment: @Joey Did you found solution for this. I really want to know this too.

Comment: @Sabo I did not. I sent an enhancement request to Apple. It doesn't seem possible to do this at this point in time (beta 4).

Comment: @Joey Any progress on this issue? Can't make it work.

Comment: `RequestsOpenAccess` needed to be put into plist to play sound

Comment: Note that my question is how to implement it while supporting the user's preference in Settings. Everything I've seen will not respect that setting and it will always be played.

Answer (score 10):

just use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),     
^{
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104);
});
```

the tirck is ,when the full access is enabled ,the sound will play ,if not ,because it's call is in the background thread will no block the main thread

Comment: Just curious how to get the various sound IDs?

Comment: it's save,and i have a keyboard posted on store

Comment: This does play the sound, but it always plays it even if the user disabled Keyboard Clicks in Settings. Surely they don't appreciate that.

Comment: Heed Apple's warning with this approach: "This is not a supported API. Third parties aren't supposed to call first party system sounds."

Comment: Wasted too much time not to contribute on SO. Given the answer has the issues outlined by Joey, I guess the only way is to use this with a switch from the keyboard container app. I cannot find a better answer.

Comment: That is what SwiftKey app uses too. Time to ask a question or edit this question may be?