# Playing system click sound in iOS keyboard extension

Tags: ios, audio, ios-keyboard-extension

I have followed the instructions on both these links:

[How to play keyboard click sound in custom keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299021/how-to-play-keyboard-click-sound-in-custom-keyboard/10299080#10299080)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html

and done the following:

header:

```
@interface Key : UIView <UIInputViewAudioFeedback>
```

implementation:

```
- (BOOL) enableInputClicksWhenVisible {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
    [self.delegate keyHit:_title];
}
```

Yet it is still not working. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code any time you want to play system click sound in a keyboard extension:

```
+ (void)keyboardClickSound {

    // Check system preference for current setting of Keyboard Click Sound.
    CFStringRef applicationID = CFSTR("/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.sounds");
    Boolean keyExistsAndHasValidFormat;
    BOOL enableInputClicks
    = CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValue(CFSTR("keyboard"), applicationID, &keyExistsAndHasValidFormat);

    // Note: If the key does not exist because it has never been changed by a user,
    //       set it to the default, YES.
    if (!keyExistsAndHasValidFormat)
        enableInputClicks = YES;

    // Play Keyboard Click Sound, if enabled.
    // Note: If Open Access=Off, no click sound.
    if (enableInputClicks)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                   ^{ AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your keyboard extension app contains "RequestsOpenAccess" field to YES,
Then keyboard click sound must need "Allow full Access" switch to On from
General > Keyboard > Keyboards > Your_keyboard setting.

If It is Off then you can not play keyboard key sound.